# SQLLite 3 Selecting column on python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a **Python 2.7** project with **SQLLite3** database and I'd like to find something from my database by using a command where the value is like this in the database: `{'Daryan': '40.2'}`

where `playerName='Daryan'` and `Time=40.2`. My Table name is 'Maps' and my the column name is 'Time'.

I don't know the `Time` value but I know the `playerName`, and this is what i tried so far:

I get 0 results:

```
this.client.room.Cursor.execute("select * from Maps where Time LIKE ?", 
                                ["{'" + playerName + "': "])
```

I get error: "Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied."

```
this.client.room.Cursor.execute("select * from Maps where Time LIKE '?%'", 
                                ["{'" + playerName])
```

What should I change to get my execution working?

Comment: You should split the one column into `playername` and `time`, `Daryan` and `40.2`. Writing complex structures to columns make queries complicated.

Comment: Try `this.client.room.Cursor.execute("select * from Maps where Time LIKE ?", ["{'" + playerName + "': %"])` but you should really find a better way to store the data like e.g.  using two columns in the table, one for player name and one for time.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @MichaelButscher i am working on seperating them and this new code you gave me worked very well, thank you so much.